# Get values from Ext.util.MixedCollection?

Tags: extjs

How can I get to the value from 'age'?
I already have 'record.data.items', but I can't get any further. I want the value of age. Can anyone help me?

`Ext.util.MixedCollection

```
...
items: Array[3]
    0: c
        data: Object
            age: "4"
            id: "1"
            name: "sam"
    1: c
    2: c
    length: 3
    __proto__: Array[0]
keys: Array[3]
length: 3
...`
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.MixedCollection

You can get at the items in the collection with the getAt() method.

To iterate through the list, loop 0 to getCount()

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < record.getCount() ; i ++){
    console.log(record.getAt(i).data.age);
}
```